# How to extract comments with data using pandas?

Tags: excel, pandas, comments

normally when we use the read function we get data only we don't get comments, sometimes those comments are also important for analysis, so any heads up would be helpful. Thank You

Comment: what `read()` function?   they exist in many libraries....   if you mean https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html it will read all data, if some of the columns are comments they will be read

Answer (score 1):

comments normally are on few random cell, hence you may have to loop through rows and cells to capture comments and Pandas may not help you, you may use openpyxl to do this

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

workbook = load_workbook('yourexcel.xlsx')
sheet1 = workbook.get_sheet_names()[0]
worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(sheet1)

for row in worksheet.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        if cell.comment:
            print(cell.comment.text)
```

Comment: okay seems a bit helpful, but I can't see my data and without data, there it's difficult looking|extracting the comments.